# AWS Beanstalk : Application not available

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Beanstalk demo application travelLog. When I run the application on the local tomcat server, the application runs properly. But when I try to deploy it on Beanstalk, I get an error HTTP:503 Application not available. I followed all the steps given on the Amazon docs page. But still I get the same error. Did anyone get the same error or has resolved the error or knows the fix. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you are targeting Java 1.6 when you are compiling the code. Currently, AWS Elastic Beanstalk only supports Java 1.6

Comment: I am using Java 1.6 only